# Deserializer never called when field is not present

Tags: rust

I have a custom serializer and deserializer. where the `a field` is of type `Option<i32>`
and turns into stringified `"i32"` when serializing or skips the field if it is `None`.

The problem is when I try to deserialize back to struct which has no  `a field` present.
The print statements are never called either

**Error**:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: Error("missing field `a`", line: 1, column: 13)',
> src/main.rs:32:45

```
use std::error::Error;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyBox {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    #[serde(serialize_with = "ser_a", deserialize_with = "de_a")]
    a: Option<i32>,
    b: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
  

    let e = MyBox {
        a: None,
        b: "oklol".to_string(),
    };

    let f: String = serde_json::to_string(&e).unwrap();
    let g: MyBox = serde_json::from_str(&f).unwrap(); // Error occurs here

    Ok(())
}

fn ser_a<S>(a: &Option<i32>, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let a = a.unwrap().to_string();
    s.serialize_str(&a)
}

fn de_a<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<Option<i32>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    println!("{:#?}", ("hello!"));
    let opt: Option<String> = Option::deserialize(d)?;

    match opt {
        Some(s) => {
            let g = i32::from_str(&s);
            match g {
                Ok(x) => {
                    println!("hello1 {:#?}", (x));
                    Ok(Some(x))
                }
                Err(x) => {
                    println!("hello2 {:#?}", (x));
                    Ok(None)
                }
            }
        }
        None => {
            println!("hello3 {:#?}", ());
            Ok(None)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you use `deserialize_with` or `with` it changes how `Option`s are treated and they are no longer optional. If you want to make the field optional, add a `#[serde(default)]` attribute.
Regarding `de_a` not being called that is by design.

Comment: OK ty. It's interesting how it works. Added the #[serde(default)] The default value is None and it skips the deserializer function altogether. OK, so adding default to option skips the deserializer when empty and sets it to None, as you said

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here.

- When using custom deserializers, `Option`s are no longer treated as optional when deserializing.
- Custom deserializers (provided via `deserialize_with`) will only be called if the field is present in the structure to be deserialized.

If you want a default value for a field that is not present, you'll have to use either `#[serde(default)]` or `#[serde(default = "path")]` ([docs here](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#default)).

---

Note that user [@jonasbb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15470286/jonasbb) already provided this answer in the comments, but I think it would be worthwhile to have it as an answer.